# Onenote math assistant: variables with double subscripts not possible?

Tags: systems-of-equations

The Onenote Math assistant is great for solving simple systems of equations. But when the variables have double subscripts (like A_gh) it doesn't seem to work. It does work when a variable has just one subscript, though (like A_g). Is there a solution/workaround for this? Since a lot of my equations need double subscripts (like M_ab, M_ba, M_bc, M_cb...).

- I tried by using a variable like "Mab", but this is interpreted as "M * a*b".
- when I type the equation in a text box, typing "_"to start the subscripts, it doesn't work.
- when I insert an equation, and then use the "subscript structure" from the equation editor menu, it doesn't work.
- when I insert an equation, and then type "_" on my keyboard (an "arrow" appears in the equation), and I go on typing the equation (the arrow symbol goes away, and the equation shows the subscripts, seems fine)... but it still doesn't work...
- ...unless: if I re-edit such an equation, and select the variable
  entirely, and retype it, using the "_" on my keyboard. If I manage to
  invoke the math assistant before the arrow symbol changes to a
  subscript, **it does work!!!**

[image: Afbeelding]

This of course is very clumsy behaviour: if I go on editing this equation, at some point the arrow symbol changes into the "normal" subscript representation, so Math assistant doens't work anymore.

Also, when I write down (with a stylus) my equations, and turning my hand writing into a math equation, it does recognise the subscripts. But this is useless, of course, since it is not with the (strange!) arrow notation of the subscripts.

So still not a real solution, simply because there seem to be two "types" of representation of the subscripts. And only the "arrow" version seems to function correctly....
Anyone an idea to solve this? I really need the double subscripts, for educational reasons.
I tried many other apps and software: Onenote Math assistant is the most untuitive solution I've found to solve systems of equations 'as if you are doing the math op paper'. Also, most students have this on their laptops anyway. Unforunately the Math assistant only seems to be available in the Onenote for windows10 version and the classroom version, NOT in the standard office 365 version. I hope this is added someday to the 365 version?